# CSS-only push nav won't hide

Tags: css, menu, navigation, slide

I'm using a css-only push nav. It works great, however I can't figure out how to make the menu hide away when a nav link is clicked. You have to manually click the menu icon for the menu to go back into hiding. However, when a link is clicked and the site jumps to a section, I want the menu to slide into hiding automatically.

Here's a fiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ex7jthnn/28/

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu" class="menu-checkbox">
<div class="menu">  
<label class="menu-toggle" for="menu"><span>Toggle</span></label>
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a class="text-right" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a class="text-right" href="#process">PROCESS</a></li>
<li><a class="text-right" href="#work">WORK</a></li>
<li><a class="text-right" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label{
cursor: pointer;
&:focus;
outline: none;
}  

.menu{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(111, 206, 204, 0.7);
width: 240px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}

label.menu-toggle{
position: absolute;    
right: -60px;
width: 75px;
height: 90px;
line-height: 0px;  
display: block;
margin-top: 30px; 
margin-right: -50px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: 50% 50% / 45px 32px no-repeat;
background-image:url(../images/menu.png);
}


a, label{
display: block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-checkbox{
display: none;
}

.menu .menu label.menu-toggle{
background: none;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked + .menu{
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this piece of code into your website, it should make the job done.

```
$('ul.mainnav > li > a').on('click', function(e){
   $('#menu').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: When I scale down the browser to test out tablet and mobile sizes, the menu seems to be very responsive. However, when I tested it out on an actual tablet and phone, the menu won't hide away again. Even clicking on the little menu icon doesn't hide it. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: i've tested this on my nexus 7 tablet and it seems to work, what kind of tablet do you use?

Comment: Hmm well that's good news. I'm using an ipad mini and an iphone

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't work on any browser when using apple tablets/mobile devices, and it doesn't work on safari period. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: here is and updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/4rLx5skh/3/ - should work, i've tested on safari 7

the problem was on webkit prefixes, look for comment i've added into fiddle and swap your code or make changes like in fiddle.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for all your help!! :)